# Windows Runtime of Windows 8 improved by Windows 10

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, win-universal-app, windows-rt, windows-10

Is the Windows Runtime library that was introduced with Windows 8 the predecessor of the Windows Universal library in Windows 10?
Or is the Windows Universal library something totally build from the ground up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same thing. The Windows Runtime for Universal Windows apps is a continuation of the Windows Runtime that first shipped in Windows 8.